# Which schema do I Need to create an app service domain?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I've a D1 plan. Followed the instructions to create a new app service domain.

Once I try to create it, it failed:

[image]

I've added Contact personal info, not sure which info are needed.

What should I do? The tutorial is step to step, not sure about the missing point...

Here's the info I've inserted:

[image]

all field. I don't see any other field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the information required by ICAAN is very important, especially the ones with the red asterisk. Kindly take time to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain
again.
[image: Watch out for the red asterisks]

Comment: Please try with another domain name and ensure your information matches the information on your credit card. Let me know how this goes, thank you.

Comment: There should be "Fields" in error message that should give you more details

Comment: Please create a support ticket on your azure portal, Microsoft support will help syn your account and this process will be possible after the syncing.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/